# What is BasicHttpBinding or WsHttpBinding in relation to a SOAP client used for?

Tags: soap-client

I am trying to communicatie with a webapplication through its SOAP service. Now in the C# code I can create a client and login, get a session id. All is well. Upon constructing this client I could have provided a binding. I am trying to read on MSDN what the binding is good for, and I feel like I am getting flooded with all technical terms that are new for me. Is it binding like data binding to a view , to automate updating things when the datasource changes? Does the binding allow the server to call the client as well? And if the binding is specified, what are its benefits and how do I use it? Can someone give a real world example of what is possible with a binding and not possible without a binding?